# Two of MySQL views are very slow

Tags: mysql

I have been trying to get this problem solved for a while now and I'm not getting anywhere. I have two views in my database that are much slower than everything else. One of the takes 1.5s to generate and the other one over 3s. I know these values would be OK if I was scanning through large amount of rows, but I am only using less than 5,000 rows per view.

The server runs on a 32GB RAM dedicated machine with 2x Intel Hexa-Core Xeon E5-2420 CPUs.

In this [screenshot](http://prntscr.com/jtjuqw) you can see my current my.cnf configuration which I generated using Percona Tools for MySQL.

The view that takes 3 seconds to generate, the code can be seen below

```
CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`easycoun_st`@`localhost` SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `view_stocktake_summary`  AS  select `stocktake_locations`.`stocktake_id` AS `stocktake_id`,(select `stocktake_master`.`store_id` from `stocktake_master` where `stocktake_master`.`id` = `stocktake_locations`.`stocktake_id`) AS `store_id`,(select `stocktake_master`.`stock_date` from `stocktake_master` where `stocktake_master`.`id` = `stocktake_locations`.`stocktake_id`) AS `stock_date`,(select sum(`stocktake_details`.`quantity` * `stocktake_details`.`unit_of_measure` + `stocktake_details`.`quantity_units`) from `stocktake_details` where `stocktake_details`.`stocktake_id` = `stocktake_locations`.`stocktake_id`) AS `total_quantity`,(select sum(`stocktake_details`.`quantity` * `stocktake_details`.`full_cost` + `stocktake_details`.`quantity_units` * `stocktake_details`.`unit_cost`) from `stocktake_details` where `stocktake_details`.`stocktake_id` = `stocktake_locations`.`stocktake_id`) AS `total_cost` from `stocktake_locations` group by `stocktake_locations`.`stocktake_id` ;
```

The Explain query can be seen [here](http://prntscr.com/jtjvqt).

I have indexes on all columns that are being used in generating the view.

The second view that I am having issues with, is as follows:

```
CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`arturl`@`localhost` SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `view_profit_master`  AS  select `stocktake_locations`.`stocktake_id` AS `stocktake_id`,(select `stocktake_master`.`store_id` from `stocktake_master` where `stocktake_master`.`id` = `stocktake_locations`.`stocktake_id`) AS `store_id`,(select `stocktake_master`.`stock_date` from `stocktake_master` where `stocktake_master`.`id` = `stocktake_locations`.`stocktake_id`) AS `stock_date`,(select sum(`store_purchases`.`cost_value`) from `store_purchases` where `store_purchases`.`stocktake_id` = `stocktake_locations`.`stocktake_id`) AS `total_purchases`,(select sum(`store_wastage`.`wastage_amount`) from `store_wastage` where `store_wastage`.`stocktake_id` = `stocktake_locations`.`stocktake_id`) AS `total_wastage`,(select sum(`store_sales`.`sale_at_cost`) from `store_sales` where `store_sales`.`stocktake_id` = `stocktake_locations`.`stocktake_id`) AS `total_sales`,(select sum(`stocktake_details`.`quantity` * `stocktake_details`.`full_cost` + `stocktake_details`.`quantity_units` * `stocktake_details`.`unit_cost`) from `stocktake_details` where `stocktake_details`.`stocktake_id` = `stocktake_locations`.`stocktake_id`) AS `total_cost` from `stocktake_locations` group by `stocktake_locations`.`stocktake_id` ;
```

And again, explain query [here](http://prntscr.com/jtjxgq).

Same as previously, all columns have indexes. Why are the two views so slow to generate? Is there something wrong with my config or is it actually the amount of subqueries?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting the joins as select columns, you can try to use proper JOINs.

```
select 
  l.stocktake_id AS 'stocktake_id',
  m.store_id as 'store_id',
  m.stock_date as 'stock_date',
  sum(d.quantity *d.unit_of_measure + d.quantity_units) as 'total_quantity',
  sum(d.quantity * d.full_cost + d.quantity_units * d.unit_cost) as 'total_cost'
from stocktake_locations l
  join stocktake_master m on m.id = l.stocktake_id
  join from stocktake_details d on d.stocktake_id = l.stocktake_id
group by l.stocktake_id, m.store_id, m.stock_date;
```

Note that the view does not include any restrictive WHERE-clauses so the only indexes MySQL will use is with joins between the tables.

Comment: Trying this with few changes as I was getting errors on line join from stocktake_details d d.stocktake_id = l.stocktake_id crashed the MySQL database completely

Comment: Added the missing ON for the JOIN which would cause a syntax error, not a crash.